# Show that a subset $K$ of the Hilbert space $L_2[0,1]$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a subset of $L_2[0,1]$ consisting of the functions $f_n(x)=(1+2^{-n})e^{2\pi inx}$, where $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Show that the subset $K$ of the Hilbert space $L_2[0,1]$ is closed.

If I want show $K$ is closed , I have to show $f_n$ converges to an element in $L_2[0,1]$. But I couldn't find that element. Or is there any other way to conclude the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\langle f_n, f_m \rangle = 0$ when $n\neq m$. Hence $f_n$ are orthogonal, and $\|f_n-f_m\|^2 = \|f_n\|^2+\|f_m\|^2 \geq 2$. In particular, $f_n$ is not Cauchy. In fact, no subsequence of $f_n$ can be Cauchy.

Now let $ g \notin K$. Then we have $\sqrt{2} \leq \|f_n-f_m\| \leq \|g-f_n\|+\|g-f_m\|$ whenever $n\neq m$. Now let $\delta = \inf_k \|g-f_k\|$. If $\delta = 0$, then there must exist a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_k \|g-f_{n_k}\| = 0$, which contradicts the previous estimate for large $k$. Hence $\delta > 0$, and consequently, $B(g,\delta) \cap K = \emptyset$. Hence $K^C$ is open, and so $K$ is closed.

Comment: More briefly, *discrete* sets are closed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to show it approaches a limit; rather what you need is to show that every limit that some subsequence approaches is already a member of the sequence.  And if you were to show that the sequence has a limit, that would not prove the set is closed.  If the limit were not a member of the sequence, then that would show that this set is *not* closed.  If you can show that any two members of this set are orthogonal to each other, that would imply that any limit point of this set (which would be a limit of some subsequence) would be in the intersection of the one-dimensional subspaces that they span.  But the only point in that intersection is $0$.  So it's enough to show that no subsequence of this sequence can approach $0$.  That implies no such subsequence can approach anything.  The set has no limit points; therefore every limit point is in the set; therefore it's closed.